# Does spherical distribution implies independence of Euclidean norm and directions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, spherical-coordinates

Here, we call a random vector $X\in\mathbb{R^n}$ follows a spherical distribution (or rotationally invariance), if $X$ satisfies that for any orthogonal matrix $Q$, $QX\stackrel{d}=X$. Is it true that $\|X\|_2$ is independent of $\frac{X}{\|X\|_2}$?

I know that in a traditional way, if $X$ has a density function $f(x^Tx)$ with $f(\cdot)\geq 0$, then by polar coordinate transformation, i.e. $x\to(r,\theta)$, we can prove that $r$ is independent of $\theta$, which implies the independence of $\|X\|_2$ and $\frac{X}{\|X\|_2}$.

But in a general case, a spherical distribution $X$ does not necessarily have density, and I have no idea in this case.

Comment: $f(x^Tx)$ is not really the density of $X$, it is the density of $X^TX=\|X\|^2$, right? Is $X$ having a density function equivalent to $X^TX$ having a density function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof

For convenience define two new random variables $R = \|X\|_2$ and $U = \frac XR$. I wish to show that the distribution functions factor. That is

$$F_{(R,U)}(r,u) = F_R(r)F_U(u)$$

Now pick arbitrary $u$ and $v$ on the unit sphere. We can then pick an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Qu = v$. Then we have the following

$$\frac {F_{(R,U)}(r,u)}{F_R(r)} = \frac{F_X(ru)}{F_R(r)} = \frac{F_X(Qru)}{F_R(r)} =\frac{F_X(rv)}{F_R(r)} =\frac{F_{(R,U)}(r,v)}{F_R(r)}$$

This means that we can pick some function $g$ such that

$$
\frac{F_{(R,U)}(r,u)}{F_R(r)} = g(u)
$$

From here we simply note that

$$F_U(u) = \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{F_{(R,U)}(r,u)}{F_R(r)} = g(u)$$

Hence we have the desired factorisation, and $U$ and $R$ are independent

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried to use distribution functions but I got stuck. Your solution is very nice!

Comment: I am trying to understand your proof. Since $X$ has a spherical distribution, we have that $F_{(R,U)}(r,u)=F_{(R,U)}(r,v)$. This means that the probability only depends on the length of $X$ and not on the direction, right? How does this imply that we can pick some function $g$ such that
$$
\frac{F_{(R,U)}(r,u)}{F_R(r)}=g(u)?
$$
It seems that the left-hand side does not depend on $u$. How do we know that the conditional distribution of $U$ given $R$ depends on $u$ but not on $r$? Thanks!